Approaches to reduce splotchiness on UNet output
I'm training a UNet to try and predict caustics, kind of as a toy problem.
An input image to the UNet is something like this:

It is trained on "ground truth" outputs like this:

It is currently predicting results like this:

I figure I've begun overfitting because the training loss is consistently dropping below the validation loss (I'm just using standard MSE over the pixels). So, my main question is: what part of the UNet architecture is producing this weird splotchiness? It almost seems like there's some visible grid in the predicted caustic...

My UNet is very standard. I'm trying to think what part of it would produce this grid-like splotchiness and then how I can tackle that. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

For reference, my code looks like this:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=3, pool_size=2, pool_type=F.max_pool2d, learn_residual=False):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()

        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.pool_type = pool_type
        self.learn_residual = learn_residual
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        
        # Encoder
        self.enc1 = self.conv_block(in_channels, 64)
        self.enc2 = self.conv_block(64, 128)
        self.enc3 = self.conv_block(128, 256)
        self.enc4 = self.conv_block(256, 512)
        
        # Bottleneck
        self.bottleneck = self.conv_block(512, 1024)
        
        # Decoder
        self.upconv4 = self.upconv_block(1024, 512)
        self.dec4 = self.conv_block(1024, 512)  # 512 (from upconv) + 512 (from enc4)
        
        self.upconv3 = self.upconv_block(512, 256)
        self.dec3 = self.conv_block(512, 256)   # 256 (from upconv) + 256 (from enc3)
        
        self.upconv2 = self.upconv_block(256, 128)
        self.dec2 = self.conv_block(256, 128)   # 128 (from upconv) + 128 (from enc2)
        
        self.upconv1 = self.upconv_block(128, 64)
        self.dec1 = self.conv_block(128, 64)    # 64 (from upconv) + 64 (from enc1)
        
        # Final Output
        self.final_conv = nn.Conv2d(64, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1) # No ReLU activation on final output
    
    def conv_block(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            # Note: Removed MaxPool2d from conv_block
        )
    
    def upconv_block(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # Encoder
        enc1 = self.enc1(x)    # [batch, 64, H, W]
        enc2 = self.enc2(self.pool_type(enc1, self.pool_size)) # [batch, 128, H/2, W/2]
        enc3 = self.enc3(self.pool_type(enc2, self.pool_size)) # [batch, 256, H/4, W/4]
        enc4 = self.enc4(self.pool_type(enc3, self.pool_size)) # [batch, 512, H/8, W/8]
        
        # Bottleneck
        bottleneck = self.bottleneck(self.pool_type(enc4, 2)) # [batch, 1024, H/16, W/16]
        
        # Decoder
        up4 = self.upconv4(bottleneck)                         # [batch, 512, H/8, W/8]
        concat4 = torch.cat([up4, enc4], dim=1)                # [batch, 1024, H/8, W/8]
        dec4 = self.dec4(concat4)                              # [batch, 512, H/8, W/8]
        
        up3 = self.upconv3(dec4)                               # [batch, 256, H/4, W/4]
        concat3 = torch.cat([up3, enc3], dim=1)                # [batch, 512, H/4, W/4]
        dec3 = self.dec3(concat3)                              # [batch, 256, H/4, W/4]
        
        up2 = self.upconv2(dec3)                               # [batch, 128, H/2, W/2]
        concat2 = torch.cat([up2, enc2], dim=1)                # [batch, 256, H/2, W/2]
        dec2 = self.dec2(concat2)                              # [batch, 128, H/2, W/2]
        
        up1 = self.upconv1(dec2)                               # [batch, 64, H, W]
        concat1 = torch.cat([up1, enc1], dim=1)                # [batch, 128, H, W]
        dec1 = self.dec1(concat1)                              # [batch, 64, H, W]
        
        # Final Output
        out = self.final_conv(dec1)                            # [batch, 3, H, W]

        if self.learn_residual:
            out += x[:, :self.out_channels, :, :]
        
        return out


